# Python Countdown w/o Sleep

Tags: python, time

I am working on a Twisted socket, but what I've heard is that if you use time.sleep while using a socket, the system hangs and the socket goes on halt. Is there any way of doing a countdown without time.sleep?

Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully useful: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.0.0/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html

Answer (score 0):

Twisted has a couple of options. You could use a simple function to check a condition.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
expire = 10
def tick():
    expire -= 1
    if expire == 0:
        reactor.stop()
        return
    reactor.callLater(1, tick)

reactor.callLater(0, tick)
reactor.run()
```

There is also twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html

```
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall

def tick():
    if expired = 0:
        reactor.stop()
        return
    do_something()

task = LoopingCall(tick)
task.start()
reactor.run()
```

If you are using a twisted application (twistd) or some other multiservice, there is also twisted.application.internet.TimerService http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.application.internet.TimerService.html

Comment: In your first example, wouldn't reactor stop completely? Is that needed? All I'm asking is the most basic countdown, where an argument has the number and if the number is reached then do something. Is that what it will do? I'm not on the right computer so I can't test really.

Comment: The reactor.stop() was just an example. It could be any function.I used reactor.stop() in the example to cause the execution to stop when the counter is reached. You probably would want some other function ;-)